Redshift | View dependencies of a table in views, function and stored procedures in every schema inside a database
I'm currently checking the dependencies of a table in a schema. I ned to know which functions/stored_procedues/views uses this table in a redshift database.
Thanks in Advance,
Sundar

Have you looked in awslabs' github repo on Redshift?  https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils
